# how to select one radio button at a time

Tags: html, css, angular

in the below code, i am trying to display radio-buttons. the problem is, when i run the code there is possibility to check all the radio-buttons at the same time. what i want to achieve is only one radio button is able to be checked at a time.in other words, the
user should not be able to select more than one radio-button, only one is selected and the rest should be unchecked.
please let me how to adapt the below code to achive that

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <input [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="areaOfCoverageForThreshold3" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold3" type="radio" (change)="toggleShowAreaOfCoverageWithThreshold3()" [(checked)]="showAreaOfCoverageForThreshold3" />
  <label id="threshold-value-3">
    {{ "SITE.AREA_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD_3" | translate }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
      <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
  <input [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="areaOfCoverageForThreshold10" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold10" type="radio" (change)="toggleShowAreaOfCoverageWithThreshold10()" [(checked)]="showAreaOfCoverageForThreshold10" />
  <label id="threshold-value-10">
    {{ "SITE.AREA_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD_10" | translate }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
      <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
  <input [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="areaOfCoverageForThreshold15" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold15" type="radio" (change)="toggleShowAreaOfCoverageWithThreshold15()" [(checked)]="showAreaOfCoverageForThreshold15" />
  <label id="threshold-value-15">
    {{ "SITE.AREA_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD_15" | translate }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
      <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
  <input [value]="3" [(ngModel)]="areaOfCoverageForThreshold20" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold20" type="radio" (change)="toggleShowAreaOfCoverageWithThreshold20()" [(checked)]="showAreaOfCoverageForThreshold20" />
  <label id="threshold-value-20">
    {{ "SITE.AREA_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD_20" | translate }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
      <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Radio Buttons `(type="radio")` are grouped by their **name** attribute and differed by their **value** attribute. So **name** attribute value `should be same`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Radio Buttons are grouped by their name and differed by their value.

So you basically have to give all of them the same name but different values (example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio):

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
  <label for="huey">Huey</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
  <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
  <label for="louie">Louie</label>
</div>
```

For your case that would look something like this:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <input [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="areaOfCoverageForThreshold3" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold" type="radio" (change)="toggleShowAreaOfCoverageWithThreshold3()" [(checked)]="showAreaOfCoverageForThreshold3" />
  <label id="threshold-value-3">
    {{ "SITE.AREA_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD_3" | translate }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
      <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
  <input [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="areaOfCoverageForThreshold10" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold" type="radio" (change)="toggleShowAreaOfCoverageWithThreshold10()" [(checked)]="showAreaOfCoverageForThreshold10" />
  <label id="threshold-value-10">
    {{ "SITE.AREA_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD_10" | translate }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
      <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
  <input [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="areaOfCoverageForThreshold15" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold" type="radio" (change)="toggleShowAreaOfCoverageWithThreshold15()" [(checked)]="showAreaOfCoverageForThreshold15" />
  <label id="threshold-value-15">
    {{ "SITE.AREA_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD_15" | translate }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
      <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
  <input [value]="3" [(ngModel)]="areaOfCoverageForThreshold20" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold" type="radio" (change)="toggleShowAreaOfCoverageWithThreshold20()" [(checked)]="showAreaOfCoverageForThreshold20" />
  <label id="threshold-value-20">
    {{ "SITE.AREA_OF_COVERAGE_FOR_THRESHOLD_20" | translate }}
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon" (click)="showInformation('SERVICE_DIST_4_AGRI')">
      <clr-icon shape="help-info" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
    </button>
  </label>
</div>
```

I just removed the numbers at the end of the "name" attribute.

Comment: would you please adding how to have access to the selected one from angular type script??

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have given them different `names`. Your code should look something like this:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <input value="0" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold3" type="radio" />
  <label id="threshold-value-3">
    Value 0

  </label>
  <input value="1" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold3" type="radio" />
  <label id="threshold-value-10">
   Value 1
  </label>
  <input value="2" name="areaOfCoverageForThreshold3" type="radio" />
  <label id="threshold-value-15">
    Value 2
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the radio inputs may have same name attribute.

For example: `name="radiogroup1"`